# Javascript 2D Arrays value search

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

Here is my javascript object-

```
var test=[
            [
                {book:"A"},
                {book:"B"}
            ]
          ]
```

In this object if I want to check whether an object with value "C" exists or not how can I do that?

Comment: just a check? or would you like to get the object? please add your try.

Comment: you can use filter function to get the object

Comment: I want to find a value in the object:- Here's my try-   if(!test[0].includes('C'))

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nested [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check agains the value.

```js
var test = [[{ book: 'A' }, { book: 'B' }]],
    check = 'c';
    
console.log(test.some(a => a.some(({ book }) => book === check))); // false
console.log(test.some(a => a.some(({ book }) => book === 'A')));   // true
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt would be:

```
let hasC = false;
for (let arr of test) {
  const obj = arr.find(b => b.book === 'C')
  if(obj) {
    hasC = true;
    break;
  }
}

console.log('does test has a book "C"? ', hasC);
```